# Solved! - Power Automate Flow - Altering the Body of the response and replace /n with /r/n

Tags: power-automate

I am creating a flow on Power Automate that calls to 2 different API's, the first one, retrieves data (Body of the response), and POST it to the second API. I a, using a custom HTTP connector.

The first calls works well and I am able to grab the data of the response and send it to the second API, however, this last API is expecting the data in a specific format and doesn't like break lines (\ln), and I need to replace them with \ln\r.

I have tried so far to loop through the data and using the option "Apply to each", and a condition for replacing the values, but it always fails. (I am not sure what I am doing or what is best way of using the actions available)

This is the query I am using:

```
replace(replace(outputs('HTTP_call_to_the_Source')?['body'], '/n', ''), '/n', '/r/n')
```

The error I get is:

> The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each_2' failed: the result
> of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression
> '@replace(body('HTTP_call_to_the_Source'), '/n', '/r/n')' is of type
> 'String'. The result must be a valid array.

No idea how to fix this and the documentation isn't helping me much.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Please see screenshot of this flow below:

[image]

UPDATE!!!

I have managed to solve this issue, I document it here in case someone else finds it useful:

First, I changed the action type, instead of apply to each, I used Compose, then I added the following function:

replace( outputs('HTTP_call_to_the_Source')?['body'], decodeUriComponent('%0A'), decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A') ) and this replaced all the \n with \r\n successfully.

Thanks all for your help

Comment: Why are you using an apply to each? What was the thinking there?

Comment: Because as it is a CSV file, my intention was to scan the document row by row, however after changing the action type, I realized that the data from the first API call seems to be downloaded as a whole string rather than a CSV because when I try to look for the Body, it can't grab it from the data, I have tried the following functions (saving the CSV data inside a variable): 
replace(variables('Sample data'), '\n', '\r\n')

split(variables('Workday data'), decodeUriComponent('%0D%0A')), and none of them replace the characters

Comment: Would you consider using a CSV to JSON converter?  From there, it'll be much easier to work with.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/

Comment: If your body isn't an array, you'll always receive that error.  Can you show us the body?  Obfuscate/mask any data you don't want us to see.

Comment: I could, but the end point only accepts CSV, and I was hoping I can just delete the data within the CSV data file and replace the characters, would you suggest to convert it to JSON, change it and then convert it back to CSV?

Comment: That approach is valid.  The `Advanced Data Operations` Json to CSV operation and vice versa has a row separator parameter where the default is `\n` but can be changed.

Comment: If you can provide a sample body json to your question, I can get a solution for you, I am sure.

Comment: This problem has been solved, please look at the update in my question. thanks all!